# Mirror animations from right hand to left hand or similar objects

Tags: armature, mirror

I promise I looked around for this answer for a long time and still haven't been able to find the answer that I'm looking for. The answer may very well just be no, but I'm looking to mirror an animation from the right hand to the left.

I am making a game where I have to hands that both perform random actions. There are way too many animations to do each one on both hands so I did them all on the right hand as seen below.[image: One handed rig with mirror modifier on the mesh of the hand.]

There is a left hand there but it is just a temporary mirror modifier on the mesh of the right hand so it doesn't have any bones. I have already copied the bones from the right hand, done the scale  X [-1] trick and while it makes the bones properly flipped, it doesn't copy the animation. If I copy the animation over to the other hand's bones, it does this-[image: bad hand]
which, as hilarious as it is, is not what I want.

Is there a way to mirror animations across a plane (in this case, the y-z plane)?